# Can I connect internal alb to private route 53 and proceed with SSL authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-route53, aws-fargate

Place the internet facing load balancer in the public area and it is sent to React. Then react calls the backend connected to the internal alb. In other words, internal alb can be called in frontend. And by applying the address of internal alb to private route 53, 'example.local' could be created. And I tried to connect this in react, but it was sent as an http request, and the react homepage was in https, causing a mixed content error.
Is there a way to solve this?

Backend and frontend are serviced by different clusters through ecs target.

Comment: The frontend has been applied to https through public route 53 and ACM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a mixed content error, then that means your requests to the backend are coming from the web browser, not a back-end server. Since you are using React, which is a front-end JavaScript framework, requests to your backend are coming from each user's laptop/desktop computer, not from your front-end web server. This means the backend API cannot be behind an internal load balancer, because then it wouldn't be accessible from the user's web browser.